# MS Access Error: 'At most one record can be returned by this subquery'

Tags: sql, ms-access

am try to connect 3 tables but am getting error `At most one record can be returned by this subquery`

My code is

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber, 
       Terms(SELECT PaymentTerms 
               FROM PSD_customerPaymentTerms 
              WHERE PSD_customerPaymentTerms.PTId = NewInvoice_1.Terms
             ) AS Terms, 
       InvoiceDate, 
       OurQuote, 
       SalesPerson(SELECT FirstName 
                     FROM Employee 
                    WHERE Employee.EmployeeId = NewInvoice_1.SalesPerson
             ) AS SalesPerson, 
       CustomerName(SELECT CustomerName 
                      FROM Customer 
                     WHERE Customer.CustomerId = NewInvoice_1.CustomerName
             ) AS CustomerName, 
       OrderNumber, 
       GrandTotal, 
       (SELECT SUM(PaymentAmount) 
          FROM Payment_Receipt 
         WHERE Payment_Receipt.InvoiceNumber=NewInvoice_1.InvoiceNumber
             ) AS AmountPaid, 
       GrandTotal-IIf(AmountPaid Is Null,0,AmountPaid) AS AmountDue, 
       (SELECT InvoiceStatus 
          FROM Payment_Receipt 
         WHERE Payment_Receipt.InvoiceNumber=NewInvoice_1.InvoiceNumber
             ) AS Status -- Error getting after adding this line.
          FROM NewInvoice_1;
```

Payment_Receipt Table contain Id, Invoice No, Customer name, Total Paid, Balance Amount, Payment Date, Payment Amount, Payment Type,Payment Remarks, InvoiceStatus.

This is my table[image: Payment Table]

How to get InvoiceStatus from this table ??

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. For the join to work, there must be a single record returned from that subquery. What happens when you run it by itself? How many rows (records) are returned? If it's more than one, you need to make the WHERE clause more restrictive so that it returns a single row.

Comment: And it's not seems to be optimal to get whatever you trying to get with this query

Comment: Am getting only one row that also display this `#Name?` values in all column

Comment: @Alexander, ok but I need to show those fields. Can you edit this code ?

Comment: @Alexander I Updates my question please read

Comment: @SriHari I'm sorry, but the nature if your question is unclear to me. Also, I'm not good with the ms-access.

Comment: Using a few JOINs instead of all those «subselect» will give you much better performance and maintainability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One general way to solve this problem is to force the subquery to return one row by using `max()` on the column:

```
select max(someColumn)
from someTable
where ...
```

In case your data has multiple rows for the where clause.

While this approach will get your query working, it may not give the results you want. More likely the where clause needs work. That said, it can be very useful when diagnosing the problem, especially if you aren't sure which subquery is causing the problem you can remove the change one subquery at a time.