# Access SQL Filter query by date for two values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an expression that shows the total inventory before all orders in and out:

(Query3 just combines the stock list with ingoing and outgoing orders, and works fine)

```
SELECT Query3.Products.ID, Query3.ProductName, Query3.StandardCost, Query3.OnHand,
  Nz(Sum([OrderJoin.Quantity]),0) AS Outgoing, Nz(Sum([Query1.Quantity]),0) AS Incoming,
  [OnHand]+[Outgoing]-[Incoming] AS OnHandAfter, [StandardCost]*[OnHandAfter] AS TotalCost
FROM Query3
GROUP BY Query3.Products.ID, Query3.ProductName, Query3.StandardCost, Query3.OnHand;
```

But what I've been trying to do is filter it by a user-inputted date. The code I have is incorrect, and I'm not sure why

```
SELECT Query3.Products.ID, Query3.ProductName, Query3.StandardCost, Query3.OnHand, 
  (SELECT NZ(Sum([OrderJoin.Quantity]),0)
  FROM Query3
  WHERE (((Query3.ShippedDate)>[Enter End Date] Or (Query3.ShippedDate) Is Null))
  GROUP BY Query3.Products.ID, Query3.ProductName, Query3.StandardCost, Query3.OnHand;
    ) AS Outgoing, 
  (SELECT NZ(Sum([Query1.Quantity]),0)
  FROM Query3
  WHERE (((Query3.DateReceived)>[Enter End Date] Or (Query3.DateReceived) Is Null))
  GROUP BY Query3.Products.ID, Query3.ProductName, Query3.StandardCost, Query3.OnHand;
    ) AS Incoming,
[OnHand]+[Outgoing]-[Incoming] AS OnHandAfter, [StandardCost]*[OnHandAfter] AS TotalCost
FROM Query3
GROUP BY Query3.Products.ID, Query3.ProductName, Query3.StandardCost, Query3.OnHand;
```

Access comes up with the error: `"At most one record can be returned by this subquery"`. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I have found that having the nested SELECTs in SELECT will only try to use one value, but I want to return multiple. So I edited the code a bit and it comes up with syntax errors and I'm not sure why:

```
SELECT Q1.Products.ID, Q1.ProductName, Q1.StandardCost, Q1.OnHand, 
  [Q1.OnHand]+[Q2.Outgoing]-[Q3.Incoming] AS OnHandAfter,
  [StandardCost]*[OnHandAfter] AS TotalCost
FROM (Query3 Q1
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT Q2.Query3.Products.ID, Q2.Query3.ProductName, Q2.Query3.StandardCost,
    Q2.Query3.OnHand, NZ(Sum([OrderJoin.Quantity]),0) AS Outgoing
  FROM Query3 Q2
  WHERE (((Query3.ShippedDate)>[Enter End Date] Or (Query3.ShippedDate) Is Null))
  GROUP BY Q2.Query3.Products.ID, Q2.Query3.ProductName, Q2,Query3.StandardCost,
    Q2.Query3.OnHand) ON Q1.Query3.Products.ID = Q2.Query3.Products.ID) 
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT Q3.Query3.Products.ID, Q3.Query3.ProductName, Q3.Query3.StandardCost,
    Q3.Query3.OnHand, NZ(Sum([Query1.Quantity]),0) AS Incoming
  FROM Query3 Q3
  WHERE (((Query3.DateReceived)>[Enter End Date] Or (Query3.DateReceived) Is Null))
  GROUP BY Q3,Query3.Products.ID, Q3.Query3.ProductName, Q3.Query3.StandardCost,
    Q3.Query3.OnHand) ON Q1.Query3.Products.ID = Q3.Query3.Products.ID
GROUP BY Q1.Query3.Products.ID, Q1.Query3.ProductName, Q1.Query3.StandardCost, Q1.Query3.OnHand;
```

Comment: It's confusing in your update to alias `Query3` as `Q2` and then use `Q2.Query3.StandardCost` instead of `Q2.StandardCost`.  In one place you have a comma instead of a period (`Q2,Query3.StandardCost`), but it's not the only syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21950269/3854195) from a similar question.  Use the `MAX` function so that the subqueries will only return a single row:

```
SELECT query3.products.id,
       query3.productname,
       query3.standardcost,
       query3.onhand,
       (
                SELECT   MAX(Nz(SUM([OrderJoin.Quantity]),0))
                FROM     query3
                WHERE    query3.shippeddate>[Enter End Date]
                OR       query3.shippeddate IS NULL
                GROUP BY query3.products.id,
                         query3.productname,
                         query3.standardcost,
                         query3.onhand;) AS outgoing,
       (
                SELECT   MAX(Nz(SUM([Query1.Quantity]),0))
                FROM     query3
                WHERE    query3.datereceived>[Enter End Date]
                OR       query3.datereceived IS NULL
                GROUP BY query3.products.id,
                         query3.productname,
                         query3.standardcost,
                         query3.onhand;) AS incoming,     
        [OnHand]+[Outgoing]-[Incoming] AS onhandafter,    
        [StandardCost]*[OnHandAfter] AS totalcost 
FROM query3 
GROUP BY query3.products.id, query3.productname, query3.standardcost, query3.onhand;
```

Comment: Do you know how I would do it to return more than one row?