# Access SQL Syntax errors using embedded SELECT

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an expression that shows the total inventory before all orders in and out:

(Query3 just combines the stock list with ingoing and outgoing orders, and works fine)

```
SELECT Query3.Products.ID, Query3.ProductName, Query3.StandardCost, Query3.OnHand,
  Nz(Sum([OrderJoin.Quantity]),0) AS Outgoing, Nz(Sum([Query1.Quantity]),0) AS Incoming,
  [OnHand]+[Outgoing]-[Incoming] AS OnHandAfter, [StandardCost]*[OnHandAfter] AS TotalCost
FROM Query3
GROUP BY Query3.Products.ID, Query3.ProductName, Query3.StandardCost, Query3.OnHand;
```

But what I've been trying to do is filter it by a user-inputted date. The code I have is incorrect, MS Access just says there's a syntax error in JOIN operation, but doesn't say where/what.

```
SELECT Q1.Products.ID, Q1.ProductName, Q1.StandardCost, Q1.OnHand, 
  [Q1.OnHand]+[Q2.Outgoing]-[Q3.Incoming] AS OnHandAfter,
  [StandardCost]*[OnHandAfter] AS TotalCost
FROM (Query3 Q1
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT Q2.Query3.Products.ID, Q2.Query3.ProductName, Q2.Query3.StandardCost,
    Q2.Query3.OnHand, NZ(Sum([OrderJoin.Quantity]),0) AS Outgoing
  FROM Query3 Q2
  WHERE (((Query3.ShippedDate)>[Enter End Date] Or (Query3.ShippedDate) Is Null))
  GROUP BY Q2.Query3.Products.ID, Q2.Query3.ProductName, Q2.Query3.StandardCost,
    Q2.Query3.OnHand) ON Q1.Query3.Products.ID = Q2.Query3.Products.ID) 
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT Q3.Query3.Products.ID, Q3.Query3.ProductName, Q3.Query3.StandardCost,
    Q3.Query3.OnHand, NZ(Sum([Query1.Quantity]),0) AS Incoming
  FROM Query3 Q3
  WHERE (((Query3.DateReceived)>[Enter End Date] Or (Query3.DateReceived) Is Null))
  GROUP BY Q3,Query3.Products.ID, Q3.Query3.ProductName, Q3.Query3.StandardCost,
    Q3.Query3.OnHand) ON Q1.Query3.Products.ID = Q3.Query3.Products.ID
GROUP BY Q1.Query3.Products.ID, Q1.Query3.ProductName, Q1.Query3.StandardCost, Q1.Query3.OnHand;
```

Comment: "The code I have is incorrect, and I'm not sure why" <---care to elaborate some more?  Are you getting incorrect results, no results at all, or an error (and if so, what does the error say)?

Comment: @user2366842 MS Access just comes up with syntax error in JOIN operation, but doesn't specify where/what

Comment: The syntax error complains about the join.  Attack that issue with a new *simpler* query in the Access query designer: just one `LEFT JOIN`; `SELECT *` at the top level; and no `GROUP BY` at the top level.  Once you have that working without error, add the second `LEFT JOIN`.  Only when you have the joins correct should you attempt to add back the top level `GROUP BY` and refine the top level `SELECT` field list.

Comment: @cfleming93 - I guess this means you abandoned the original question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/35435412/3854195)?  Would have been nice to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple problems:

1. Your syntax should be `<table/alias>.<field>` when referring to a
   field. For example: `Q2.Query3.Products.Id` makes no sense, perhaps `Q2.ID` is what is meant? Which table and which field are you going for here?
2. Your subqueries need to have an Alias. When you do `FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT field FROM table) ON..` it should be `FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT field FROM table) AS <Alias> ON..`
3. You can not join ON an
   alias that is declared in a subquery. You need to join on the alias
   of the subquery which you need to supply yet (point 2)
4. Your GROUP BY contains the first 4 fields in your result set, but the remaining two `OnHandAfter` and `TotalCost` are not being aggregated using Sum, Avg, Max, etc..

Your format should look something like:

```
SELECT Q1.ID,
    Q1.ProductName,
    Q1.StandardCost,
    Q1.OnHand,
    SUM([Q1.OnHand] + [Q2_sub.Outgoing] - [Q3_sub.Incoming]) AS OnHandAfter,
    SUM([StandardCost] * [OnHandAfter]) AS TotalCost
FROM 
    (
        Query3 Q1 
        LEFT JOIN 
            (
                SELECT Q2.ID,
                    Q2.ProductName,
                    Q2.StandardCost,
                    Q2.OnHand,
                    NZ(Sum([OrderJoin.Quantity]), 0) AS Outgoing
                FROM Query3 Q2
                WHERE (
                        (
                            (Query3.ShippedDate) > [Enter End Date]
                            OR (Query3.ShippedDate) IS NULL
                            )
                        )
                GROUP BY Q2.ID,
                    Q2.ProductName,
                    Q2.StandardCost,
                    Q2.OnHand
            ) Q2_Sub ON Q1.ID = Q2_Sub.ID
    )
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Q3.ID,
        Q3.ProductName,
        Q3.StandardCost,
        Q3.OnHand,
        NZ(Sum([Query1.Quantity]), 0) AS Incoming
    FROM Query3 Q3
    WHERE (
            (
                (Query3.DateReceived) > [Enter End Date]
                OR (Query3.DateReceived) IS NULL
                )
            )
    GROUP BY Q3,
        Query3.ID,
        Q3.ProductName,
        Q3.StandardCost,
        Q3.OnHand
    ) Q3_Sub ON Q1.ID = Q3_Sub.ID
GROUP BY Q1.ID,
    Q1.ProductName,
    Q1.StandardCost,
    Q1.OnHand;
```

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. It's now coming up with "Your query does not include the specific expression '[Q1.OnHand] + [Q2_sub.Outgoing] - [Q3_sub.Incoming]' as part of an aggregate function. Do you know what that means?

Comment: You are grouping by 4 fields, but you are not specifying how intend the database to group by `[Q1.OnHand] + [Q2_sub.Outgoing] - [Q3_sub.Incoming]` or `[StandardCost] * [OnHandAfter]`. I assume you probably want to sum those? So you'll need to do either `sum([Q1.OnHand] + [Q2_sub.Outgoing] - [Q3_sub.Incoming])` or `sum([Q1.OnHand]) + sum([Q2_sub.Outgoing]) - sum([Q3_sub.Incoming])`

Comment: I've added that to the answer as well.

Comment: Thank you this works, just one small thing now is for products that have multiple orders they double up the value of Outgoing/Incoming (i.e. Coffee has one order of 25 and one order of 5, and it comes in the results as 60). Do you know why it's doing that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, it but looks like you didn't alias your subqueries.  You had Q2 and Q3 inside the subqueries but not outside.  The aliases are contextual, so outside of the subqueries they don't mean anything.  If you move them outside, I think it will help.

I think you also have some alias confusion.  Mr. Miyagi from Karate Kid says to "do or do not," but you seem to be using them and then not using them.

Also, Access goes a little crazy with parentheses.  Sometimes I like to remove as many as possible to see what's actually going on.

To help illustrate this, I renamed your aliases on your subqueries to be X instead of Q.

```
SELECT
  Q1.Products.ID, Q1.ProductName, Q1.StandardCost, Q1.OnHand, 
  [Q1.OnHand]+[Q2.Outgoing]-[Q3.Incoming] AS OnHandAfter,
  [StandardCost]*[OnHandAfter] AS TotalCost
FROM
  Query3 Q1
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT
    X2.Products.ID, X2.ProductName, X2.StandardCost,
    X2.OnHand, NZ(Sum(X2.[Quantity]),0) AS Outgoing
  FROM Query3 X2
  WHERE
    X2.ShippedDate > [Enter End Date] Or X2.ShippedDate Is Null
  GROUP BY
    X2.Products.ID, X2.ProductName, X2.StandardCost, X2.OnHand
  ) Q2 ON Q1.Products.ID = Q2.Products.ID
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT
    X3.Products.ID, X3.ProductName, X3.StandardCost,
    X3.OnHand, NZ(Sum([X3.Quantity]),0) AS Incoming
  FROM Query3 X3
  WHERE
    Query3.DateReceived > [Enter End Date] Or X3.DateReceived Is Null
  GROUP BY
    X3.Products.ID, X3.Query3.ProductName, X3.StandardCost, X3.OnHand
  ) Q3 ON Q1.Products.ID = Q3.Products.ID
GROUP BY
  Q1.Products.ID, Q1.ProductName, Q1.StandardCost, Q1.OnHand;
```

Also, on your third to last line you have a typo:

```
GROUP BY Q3,Query3
```

That comma is probably not what you meant.